# Getting address of Java web service within the web service itself

Tags: java, web-services, url

Let's say, I am hosting a Java web service at `http://dev01:8080/ABC/theWS`. The web service is implemented using JAX-WS and JAXB annotations.

How do I get the address (`http://dev01:8080/ABC/theWS`) from within the web service itself, in order to use the address within the web service programmatically?

The web service is hosted in Tomcat, and was deployed as a war file.

- `dev01:8080` is the root.
- `ABC` is the name of the war file.
- `` `theWS `` comes from the `/META-INF/web.xml`, something that I can defined it.

I may have complete control over the server and the war file, so I can just hard code the address. However, this is what I don't want to do.

I know how to get the host name, but not the port and the rest of them.

Comment: Please provide the name of technology you use to implement web services—the answer may depend on it.

Comment: Also please note that usually web service will be behind an application proxy or load balancer; the address web service serves on usually has nothing to do with the address clients use. Which address do you need?

Comment: @alf basically, the web service that I am trying to create is for callback. I need to tell the client of the callback service what the address is, in my callback service.

Comment: @alf I am using JAX-WS and JAXB annotations.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not clear why do you need this address. Are you going to call some other service and pass link to be called back? Then, again, are you sure you're not behind a proxy or LB?

Comment: @alf I'm sorry, I am new to this, and not sure what you are asking. I need the address, and my service will pass it to some other service.